# Good resources to learn about Event Driven Architecture

Tags: architecture, soa, messaging, event-driven, eda

Looking for books, blogs, web sites or videos.

At the moment I am getting a lot of value from the blogs of Udi Dahan and Greg Young, but I was wondering if there are any other experts out there worth listening to?

Comment: Good question. I would be also interested :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are the sources that I used for my study into EDA.

SOA, EDA, BPM and CEP are all Complementary (David Luckhamm)
http://complexevents.com/2007/04/30/soa-eda-bpm-and-cep-are-all-complementary/soa-eda-bpm-and-cep-are-all-complementary/

The Growing Role of Events in Enterprise Applications (W. Roy Schulte / Gartner)
http://www.gartner.com/DisplayDocument?doc_cd=116129

Event Driven Architecture Overview (Brenda M. Michelson)
http://www.omg.org/soa/Uploaded%20Docs/EDA/bda2-2-06cc.pdf

Complex Event Processing in the Real World (Oracle)
http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/soa/oracle-complex-event-processing-066421.pdf

Event Driven SOA: A Better Way to SOA (Tibco)
http://www.tibco.jp/multimedia/wp-event-driven-soa_tcm52-803.pdf

Site of David Luckham
http://www.complexevents.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the links are broken now

Comment: Refreshed the links

Answer (score 3):

2 white papers from complex event processing product vendors:

http://www.tibco.com/multimedia/leverage-complex-event-processing-to-improve-operational-performance_tcm8-2439.pdf

http://www.oracle.com/technologies/soa/docs/oracle-complex-event-processing.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Opher Etzion is one of IBM's Event processing leads and has a blog:
http://epthinking.blogspot.com/

There's soon going to be a book on EDA, CEP and all things event processing by Manning:
http://www.manning.com/etzion/

A good (if somewhat overly complete ;-) article on developerWorks:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-eventprocessing/

Answer (score 3):

You can look at these books:

1. [**Event Processing in Action** by Opher Etzion and Peter Niblett](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182218)
2. [**The Power of Events: An Introduction to Complex Event Processing in Distributed Enterprise Systems** by David Luckham](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201727897)

Good blog about SOA and EDA: [SOA and EDA](http://soa-eda.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The rulecore blog has various things on CEP: [Marco on CEP](http://www.rulecore.com/CEPblog)